# Custom WordPress Query

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

I am trying to add shortcode to create custom homepage in WordPress.

Here is my code:

```
function custom_query()
{
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'limit' => '5',
        ),$atts));

        //The Query
    query_posts('showposts=3&orderby=date&order=DESC&category_name='.$name);
        //The Loop
       if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$return .= '<div class="posts-title">'.$title.'</div>';
$return .= '<div class="posts">';
$return .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumb').'</a>';
$return .= '</div>';

endwhile;
endif;
$return .= '</div>';
        //Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
return $return;
}
add_shortcode('custom_query', 'custom_query');
```

I tried it on two ways:

```
[custom query name=sport title=Sport News]
[custom_query name="sport" title="Sport News"]
```

Output will still show latest WordPress posts, not from a category entered in $name and even  $title doesn't showing.
I done this with google help and tutorials, I am not a professional coder so if someone can help me to resolve this, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Output will still show latest WordPress posts, not from a category entered in $name and even $title doesn't showing

This means your `$title` and `$name` are empty. Please check it once again and make sure you are getting proper values inside the function.

EDIT:

Found some errors in your code,

try the following

```
function custom_query_fun( $atts)
{
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'name' => '',
        'title' => '',
        'limit' => '5',
        ),$atts,'custom_query'));

        //The Query
    query_posts('showposts=3&orderby=date&order=DESC&category_name='.$name);
        //The Loop
       if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

$return .= '<div class="posts-title">'.$title.'</div>';
$return .= '<div class="posts">';
$return .= '<a href="'.get_permalink($post->ID).'" title="">'.get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id, 'thumb').'</a>';
$return .= '</div>';

endwhile;
endif;
$return .= '</div>';
        //Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
return $return;
}
add_shortcode('custom_query', 'custom_query_fun');
```

Comment: $atts was missing. Thanks a lot.